# Get application id by name

Tags: facebook

I need to get an application's category. In order to get that information from the graph api I need to get it's application id. However, all that I have access to is the application name that is in the URL.

I have: http://apps.facebook.com/graffitiwall

I need: https://graph.facebook.com/2439131959

Is there anyway to translate "graffittiwall" into "2439131959"?

*Note: I cannot simply use the name because the graph API **only** looks up users and pages by name.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think retrieveing an application's info through application's name is possible with Facebook Graph API. You need to have the unique id of the application in order to access its basic information.

An interesting idea would be going through users' [apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) to find the ids of different application. Then you can get the category of the application from app id.

Comment: This page seems to indicate that it should be able to be done throgh FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application/.

Unfortunately, it isn't working. I filed a bug with facebook.

Comment: So you're saying that you queried the application table and it did not return you the id's of the applications, is that correct?

Comment: I was using FQL wrong. This is how I eventually got it working:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+app_id,canvas_name,category+FROM+application+WHERE+canvas_name="graffitiwall"

Comment: In my case, `SELECT app_id FROM application WHERE namespace = 'phasetenapp'` is also working.

Answer (score 8):

i think facebook have change their field name canvas_name to namespace.

so now you can get this simply replace canvas_name with namespace.like

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+app_id,namespace,category+FROM+application+WHERE+namespace=%22graffitiwall%22

Comment: You can find the ID on the permissions page (when you haven't given permissions to the app). You can see it on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The FQL API provides useless functionality for querying the application table (and apprequest table for that matter).  For example, I would like to know the applications my friends are using, but cannot get that information because the index on apprequest combines recipient_uid and app_id, so even trying to query the apps I use fails, as follows:

SELECT app_id FROM apprequest WHERE recipient_uid = me()

Also, the apprequest table seems faulty because this query returns no results:

SELECT app_id, message FROM apprequest WHERE app_id IN(SELECT app_id FROM application WHERE namespace = 'lucky_slots') AND recipient_uid = me()

Even though this query returns a valid app_id...

SELECT app_id FROM application WHERE namespace = 'lucky_slots'

And I have a notification from that app on my timeline