# Android: how to get the app name into our textview

Tags: android, facebook

[image]

I have a `DialogBox` with a `TextView`,suppose my app is MyFriendsSecrets..I am sending a post from my app, how to get my Application name into the `TextView` ( example: from above pic: "via MyFriendSecrets")
Any suggestions is appreciated. i have a `JSON` obj as below

JSONObject me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));

Comment: Why not simply have a field "app_name" in the strings.xml folder and use that?

Comment: I quickly deleted that. This is a facebook specific question. I am actually struggling with the facebook api myself but i believe that you need to mess with the Graph API. When facebook allows your application to post to a users wall it will display the postings apps name like your above pic. I believe this will be an action that you will need to have approved by facebook. They want to make sure that you post meaningful stuff. Look inside your app dashboard click on open graph on the left pane and you will see the place to create a new action.

Comment: @doubleA..exactly u are right it post our app name ..my question is how to make a call to get that same exact name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run an FQL query targeting the [application table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application). Since you working on your own App and will have access to it's App ID, constructing this query will be very easy.

Try this piece of code:

```
String queryApp = "SELECT display_name, namespace  FROM application WHERE app_id=284752504943219";
Bundle paramsApp = new Bundle();
paramsApp.putString("method", "fql.query");
paramsApp.putString("query", queryApp);
String resultApp = Utility.mFacebook.request(paramsApp);
Log.e("APP RESULT", resultApp);

JSONArray JAApp = new JSONArray(resultApp);

for (int i = 0; i < JAApp.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject JOApp = JAApp.getJSONObject(i);

    String getDisplayName = JOApp.getString("display_name");
    Log.e("DISPLAY NAME", getDisplayName);
}
```

The **display_name** field in the query will return the name of the App as is shown on Facebook when posting via the App (as shown in the picture attached to the OP). Parse the result and set it to your `TextView`.

Since this queries the Facebook API directly, you will not have to worry about manually changing *strings* if you were to change the name of the App via the Facebook Developer Console.

Comment: ..wow this is eaxctly what i want thnak you ...also found similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991986/get-application-id-by-name

Comment: @teekib: Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: iam directly parsing the the url ...can i do that?

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+app_id,namespace,category+FROM+application+WHERE+namespace=graffitiwall

Comment: I am afraid, I am not quite sure about firing the query in a URL. :-(

In all honesty though, FQL already simplifies a lot of things.

Comment: @teekib: It is a method in the `Utility` class. If you are not sure, you can cast an instance of the `Facebook` class and use that. For example: `fbInstance.request(....)`

Answer (score 0):

its very simple just paste this code in string.xml

```
<string name="app_name">youAppName</string>
```

then in your javacode do like this

```
String appName = this.getString(R.string.app_name);

TextView appTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.appTextView);
appTextView.setText(appName);
```

cheers!!!!!

Comment: if i put in string.xml .. if i want to change the app name i have to change the string name too...actually how the facebook takes the appname and posts to its wall?

Comment: @teekib : what you want to get `via` in your application or want to send `via` from your application?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K..facebook allows your application to post to a users wall it will display the postings apps name like  above pic...how to get that app name into my text feild

Comment: what iam doing.. i iam making exact post like fb ..so when the fb takes my appname i want to call that app name too

Comment: @teekib : how you are posting app name to facebook?

Comment: thats is what i wanna find..in general when facebook posts from our application it auomaticall takes our app name and send it as via...

Comment: @teekib then post your code how you are posting other things then i will edit for u

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20992/discussion-between--k-and-teekib)

Comment: i retrieved the profile pic, same way i have to retrieve the appname from facebook . its the name i registered with facebook

Answer (score 0):

If you define your app name in the androidmanifest like

```
<application 
    ...
    android:label="@string/app_name">
 </application>
```

you can directly enter your app name `getString(R.string.app_name)` and only have 1 location, where your app name is defined

That's the name of your app... On an android device, on yourdropbox,... I assume, facebook uses the this real app name as well

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find some relief w/android.content.pm.PackageManager?  This will give you access to information declared within the manifest.