# Facebook SDK, how to request App Name

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: how to get the app name into our textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836918/android-how-to-get-the-app-name-into-our-textview)

hi iam trying  to get appname from facebook but no success..doing as below

```
String queryApp = "SELECT  namespace  FROM application WHERE app_id=xxxxxxxxxxx";
                Bundle paramsApp = new Bundle();
                paramsApp.putString("method", "fql.query");
                paramsApp.putString("query", queryApp);
                String resultApp = Util.facebook.request(paramsApp);

                Log.e("APP RESULT", resultApp);

                JSONArray JAApp = new JSONArray(resultApp);

                for (int i = 0; i < JAApp.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JOApp = JAApp.getJSONObject(i);

                    String getDisplayName = JOApp.getString("display_name");
                    Log.e("DISPLAY NAME", getDisplayName);
                }
```

the above code is not working..can i achive this using facebookasyncrunner

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

// all your paramsApp bundle code
...

mAsyncRunner.request(paramsApp, new BaseRequestListener() {
   ...
});
```

but bot sure how to use it...Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to request https://graph.facebook.com/[APP_ID]

Example:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/102452128776
```