# Facebook app id from url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to target ads on facebook for certain app but I need their app id.
These app aren't mine and I can't get the app id from the URL because facebook changed it.
The applications URL's are now like: `https://apps.facebook.com/app_name` and not like: `https://apps.facebook.com/APP_ID`

Do you have an idea how can I get the app id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get application id by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991986/get-application-id-by-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer for you should be in this thread [Get application id by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991986/get-application-id-by-name)

It's basically this FQL query:
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+app_id,namespace,category+FROM+application+WHERE+namespace=%22graffitiwall%22